# Varying intensity in the frames captured by camera (uEye)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera

I have been using Matlab to capture images from an uEye Camera at regular
intervals and use them for processing. The following is the small piece of
code that I am using to achieve that,

```
h=actxcontrol('UEYECAM.uEyeCamCtrl.1','position',[250 100 640 480]);
d=h.InitCamera(1);
check = 1;
str_old = 'img000.jpeg';
m = h.SaveImage('img000.jpeg');
pause(60);
```

And following are the images captured by the camera. There was no change in the
lighting conditions outside but you can notice the difference in the intensity
levels in the image captured by the camera.

[image]

Is there any reason for this?

**Solved thanks to Zaphod**

Allow sometime for the camera to adjust its exposure. I did it by moving the `pause` 
statement to just after the `InitCamera()` command to delay the image capture by the
camera and give it enough time to adjust itself.

Comment: Does this happen at the start of capture? There could be a chance that the camera is adjusting its exposure on startup. As a test, disable the auto exposure and see what happens.

Comment: @Zaphod I moved the `pause` command right after the `.InitCamera()`. It solved it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @baptu88 You should post it as an answer and accept it, to help future users facing the same problem (or delete this question altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved thanks to Zaphod**

Allow sometime for the camera to adjust its exposure. I did it by moving the pause statement to just after the InitCamera() command to delay the image capture by the camera and give it enough time to adjust itself.

```
h=actxcontrol('UEYECAM.uEyeCamCtrl.1','position',[250 100 640 480]);
d=h.InitCamera(1);
pause(60);
check = 1;
str_old = 'img000.jpeg';
m = h.SaveImage('img000.jpeg');
```